# MySQL latest record from table

Tags: mysql

How can I select the latest records (=MAX(order_history_id) from this table (one [latest] row per order_id):

```
+----------------+--------+-------+----------+
|order_history_id|order_id|trackc |date_added|
+----------------+--------+-------+----------+
|      4400      |   1000 | text  | 2014-9-24|
|      4401      |   1001 | text2 | 2014-9-26|
|      4410      |   1000 | text3 | 2014-9-29|
|      4411      |   1003 | text4 | 2014-9-20|
+----------------+--------+-------+----------+
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE  trackc <>  '' GROUP BY order_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.* from order_history t1
inner join(
    select order_id,max(order_history_id) as order_history_id
    from order_history
    where ifnull(trackcode,'') <> ''
    group by order_id
) as t2 on t1.order_history_id = t2.order_history_id
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any reason why this query is not working for the following data?https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt4kzkj51buuimy/Screenshot%202015-09-27%2023.36.52.png?dl=0

Comment: is column `trackc` exists in your table? if yes, try to put ifnull. I edited my answer by the way.

Comment: For some reason I am getting wrong data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikccfylaisjnot4/Screenshot%202015-09-27%2023.41.38.png?dl=0

order_history_id=4885 should be ZB...... and not WE123...

Comment: hmmm I am now getting "Unknown column 'order_history.trackcode' in 'order clause'" -> of course the column exists.

Comment: @Adrian how can you get error `unknown column order_history.trackcode` since I didn't put that in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from order_history as oh inner join (
    SELECT MAX(order_history_id) AS max_id, order_id
    FROM order_history
    GROUP BY order_id
) as t ON t.max_id = oh.order_history_id
WHERE oh.trackc <>  ''
```

The sub-query extract the max value for every order_id. Than joins the found values with order_history and extracts every fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
 select or.order_history_id,or.order_id,or.trackc,or.date_added From order_history or
 order by or.order_id Desc
 limit 1;
```